# Grouping items in two lists

Tags: python

Give these two lists:

```
I[2]: list1 = ['r1', 'r1', 'r1', 'r2', 'r2', 'r3']

I[3]: list2 = [1,2,3,1,2,1]
```

What is the Pythonic way to construct the following dictionary?

```
I[5]: mydict
O[5]: {'r1': {'n1': 1, 'n2': 2, 'n3': 3}, 'r2': {'n1': 1, 'n2': 2}, 'r3': 'n1'}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having difficulty working out how you get logically from one to the other. Can you explain the rule?

Comment: I think it's whenever there's a different element in list1, there starts a new key : dictionary. In the dictionary you have it map to the index of the list2, like `'n'+str(list2[index]) : list2[index]`

Comment: This is a single operation where I use reading a dataset in a logical way. R is a flight number, n is the flight leg I am interested from within the dataset. Eventually my data dictionary will have a form similar to mydict['r1']['n1'] = data_instance()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l1 = ['r1', 'r1', 'r1', 'r2', 'r2', 'r3']
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]

d = {}
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
  d[i] = d.get(i, {})
  d[i]['n%s' % j] = j
```

Alternatively:

```
l1 = ['r1', 'r1', 'r1', 'r2', 'r2', 'r3']
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]

d = dict((i, {}) for i in set(l1))
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
  d[i]['n%s' % j] = j
```

Comment: My only question is, why bother converting `l1` into a set? A dict already has unique keys, so there is no point (or is there??).

Comment: Sure, it means you only create 3 new dicts rather than 6 (3 of which are thrown away when you overwrite the unique keys)

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. I thought of using `set` for that reason, but it seemed irrelevant with the limited number of keys. I wonder how much of an impact it'd be on a larger set of dicts.

Comment: Using OrderedDict instead of a regular dictionary (just to keep things in order since I have about 45 items in each lists) I include your code in my script.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly too pythonic, someone could improve on this:

```
l1 = ["r1", "r1", "r1", "r2", "r2", "r3"]
l2 = [1,2,3,1,2,1]

d = {}
for i in xrange(len(l1)):
    v = d.get(l1[i], {})
    v["n" + str(l2[i])] = l2[i]
    d[l1[i]] = v
print d
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it in two steps, first create your dict of dicts, each k is an element from `list1` with associated empty dict.

```
d = dict((k, {}) for k in list1)
```

Iterate over `list1` using `enumerate` to get the index of the item in `list2`, and update proper dictionary.

```
for i, k in enumerate(list1):
    d[k]['n%d' % list2[i]] = list2[i]
```

Or better using zip to get key and proper value at the same time (as in [bluepnume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009985/grouping-items-in-two-lists/6010043#6010043)'s answer):

```
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k]['n%d' % v] = v
```

Comment: That's a strange way to update a dictionary value. `dict.update({x:y})` -> `d[x] = y`

Comment: Yeah generally not used for a single value. Dunno why I did that, just the first thing that popped into my head this morning, `update` is really useful when you have another dict to update the first with. And you already show the other way in your example, so I didn't feel like changing it...but maybe I should :D

Comment: Although using `zip` is more pythonic than using `enumerate`, so I tend to favor your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = ['r1', 'r1', 'r1', 'r2', 'r2', 'r3']
list2 = [1,2,3,1,2,1]
mydict = defaultdict(dict)
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    mydict[a]['n%s' %b] = b
```